# (standard_in) 1: parse error with comparing decimals

Tags: bash

I keep getting a parse error and have tried to check the code but I can't see what could be wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Please enter first: "
read first
echo -n "Please enter second: "
read second
echo -n "Please enter third: "
read third
si=$(echo "scale=4; $first/$second"| bc -l)
il=$(echo "scale=4; $second/$third"| bc -l)
six=$(echo "scale=4; 0.66/1"| bc -l)

if (( $(echo "scale=4; $si -gt $six" | bc -l) )) && (( $(echo "scale=4; $il -gt $six" | bc -l) ))
    then
    echo "Value is a"
    elif (( $(echo "scale=4; $si -lt $six" | bc -l) ))
    then
    echo "Value is b"
    elif (( $(echo "scale=4; $il -lt $six" | bc -l) ))
then
    echo "Value is c"
else
    echo "Value is d"
fi
```

Comment: Why do you think `-lt` is the way to compare numbers in `bc`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `-lt` and `-gt` in `bc` scripts, but these are not operators in `bc`. Replace all occurrences of `-lt` and `-gt` with `<` and `>`, respectively.

```
if (( $(echo "scale=4; $si > $six" | bc -l) )) && (( $(echo "scale=4; $il > $six" | bc -l) ))
    then
    echo "Value is a"
    elif (( $(echo "scale=4; $si < $six" | bc -l) ))
    then
    echo "Value is b"
    elif (( $(echo "scale=4; $il < $six" | bc -l) ))
then
    echo "Value is c"
else
    echo "Value is d"
fi
```

Also, the first condition can be combined using a single `bc`:

```
if (( $(echo "scale=4; $si > $six && $il > $six" | bc -l) ))
```